# What would be proper schema for the following situation?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I need to create a database table in which I have the following three fields mainly:

1. ID(default auto incrementing).
2. User_id( starting from 1000 ,auto incrementing)
3. Email

So, I want to set Email to be unique ,not null( Primary key ),but also I want to make sure that User_id remains unique ( that can be solved by setting unique  key ) and I also want it to never be set as null. So, how I can achieve this? I am using MySQL BTW.

PS:  I am not much good to this schema building for the current time. So, ignore any silly mistakes.

Comment: Why do you want email to be the primary key? Wouldn't you be better off having ID as the primary key?

Comment: @Fred Email would be enter by user ,so i want it to be unique and never null so,,,

Comment: You don't have to make it the primary key to achieve that.

Comment: @Fred then how i can make my email unique( although i can check programmatically before entering email but still any other  way exist in db)

Comment: Either of the two lines after the table create in my answer below will prevent duplicates.  If you try to enter a duplicate SQL will throw you an error.  However for a better user experience check the email they enter and let them know before they hit submit if they entered a duplicate email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for something like this

```
CREATE TABLE USERS
(
        ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        User_Id INT AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000,
        Email VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
)
```

And then

```
ALTER TABLE USERS ADD UNIQUE (Email)
```

Or if you intend to search on the Email field

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX inx_users_email ON USERS  (Email)
```

You are better of using the Id field as your primary key.  The PK is not meant to change and is used to identify the record.  What happens if your user changes email address?

Comment: ,Its very rare the user gonna change email in my app,but still i wanna whats this gonna effect when i have Email as my pk and user change it frequently

Comment: If you use email as your primary key and then change it you would have to update everything that identifies that record by the primary key.  My name is Fred, it is what all my friends and family know me as.  Imagine I decided to call myself Harry one day, I would have to tell everyone that knew me that my name had changed or they wouldn't know who Harry was.  Kind of the same thing.  If you use Id as your PK you chan change the Email as much as you like because the record is identified by Id.

Answer (score 0):

Auto_INCREMENT ensures column has unique values and can never be null.